# Check user input formatting in python for strptime()

Tags: python, input, time, format, strptime

In my program I take user input and then parse it using strptime().  This works mostly, but will throw an error if the input isn't formatted correctly.  Is there a way I can check the format before parsing it so I can ask the user to re-enter?

Comment: How about `try`/`except`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the try statement is useful as it allows you to catch exceptions and deal with them.  I am guessing that ValueError is the exception being thrown.

try:
    time.strptime(whatever)
except ValueError:
    # deal with it